# Query/Join condition with performance hit 170sec vs 500ms

Tags: sql, performance, join, indexing, mariadb

perhaps you can help me to clarify what happens here. I've really no clue why my queries perform like that

I am using, for my circumstances, a bigger select query containing eight joins to itself, three to others, which calculates working hours on a monthly/yearly basis, limited to selected employees (contracts)

If I run the query below, the execution time is about 170sec, problematic section is marked.

If I add `and ueberstunden.id >= 1` to the ON clause of the faulty join, the query executes in about 500ms. Why is there such a difference ? `id` is an autoincrement primary key. So always >= 1, which makes my addition useless in my opinion.

I also added the output of `analyse ...` from both runs at end. They show a difference for the type column:

```
+--+-----------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-----+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table             |type  |possible_keys                                                  |key                                      |key_len|ref                            |rows |r_rows  |filtered|r_filtered|Extra                                          |
+--+-----------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-----+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
.
// no addition:
|1 |SIMPLE     |ueberstunden      |ALL   |PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |NULL                                     |NULL   |NULL                           |60689|60868.00|50.57   |0         |Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)|
.
.
// added ueberstunden.id >= 1:
|1 |SIMPLE     |ueberstunden      |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1   |1.00   |50.57   |25.78     |Using where                                    |
.
+--+-----------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-----+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

This difference brought me to the mysql/mariadb docs, saying that type: ALL is in most cases  caused by bad or missing indexes. But why works it for the other joins then ? Is there somehow an implicit index or similar ?

Thank you very much!

query:

```sql
select facilities.name                             AS einrichtung,
               accounting_records.contract_id              AS cid,
               CONCAT(users.surname, ', ', users.forename) AS name,
               users.enr                                   AS enr,
               ROUND(SUM(ist.value) / 60, 3)               AS ist,
               ROUND(SUM(nsf.value) / 60, 3)               AS nsf,
               ROUND(SUM(ssf.value) / 60, 3)               AS ssf,
               ROUND(SUM(fsf.value) / 60, 3)               AS fsf,
               ROUND(SUM(nsp.value) / 60, 3)               AS nsp,
               ROUND(SUM(ssp.value) / 60, 3)               AS ssp,
               ROUND(SUM(fsp.value) / 60, 3)               AS fsp,
               ROUND(SUM(diff_soll_ist.value) / 60, 3)     AS diff_soll_ist,
               ROUND(SUM(ueberstunden.value) / 60, 3)      AS ueberstunden,
               SUM(u_monat.value) * -1                     AS u_monat,
               SUM(u_jahr.value)                           AS u_jahr
        from `accounting_records`
                 inner join `contracts` on `accounting_records`.`contract_id` = `contracts`.`id`
                 inner join `facilities` on `contracts`.`facility_id` = `facilities`.`id`
                 inner join `users` on `contracts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
                 left join `accounting_records` as `ist`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `ist`.`id` and `ist`.`account_id` = 1 and
                              `ist`.`value` > 0 and month(`ist`.`date`) = '04' and year(`ist`.`date`) = 2021
                 left join `accounting_records` as `nsf`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `nsf`.`id` and `nsf`.`salary_type_id` = 6 and
                              month(`nsf`.`date`) = '04' and year(`nsf`.`date`) = 2021
                 left join `accounting_records` as `ssf`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `ssf`.`id` and `ssf`.`salary_type_id` = 7 and
                              month(`ssf`.`date`) = '04' and year(`ssf`.`date`) = 2021
                 left join `accounting_records` as `fsf`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `fsf`.`id` and `fsf`.`salary_type_id` = 8 and
                              month(`fsf`.`date`) = '04' and year(`fsf`.`date`) = 2021
                 left join `accounting_records` as `nsp`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `nsp`.`id` and `nsp`.`salary_type_id` = 9 and
                              month(`nsp`.`date`) = '04' and year(`nsp`.`date`) = 2021
                 left join `accounting_records` as `ssp`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `ssp`.`id` and `ssp`.`salary_type_id` = 10 and
                              month(`ssp`.`date`) = '04' and year(`ssp`.`date`) = 2021
                 left join `accounting_records` as `fsp`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `fsp`.`id` and `fsp`.`salary_type_id` = 11 and
                              month(`fsp`.`date`) = '04' and year(`fsp`.`date`) = 2021
                 left join `accounting_records` as `diff_soll_ist`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `diff_soll_ist`.`id` and
                              `diff_soll_ist`.`account_id` in (1, 6) and month(`diff_soll_ist`.`date`) = '04' and
                              year(`diff_soll_ist`.`date`) = 2021
            --
            -- start problematic join is here
            --
                 left join `accounting_records` as `ueberstunden`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `ueberstunden`.`id` and
                              `ueberstunden`.`account_id` in (1, 6) and `ueberstunden`.`date` <= '2021-04-30'
            --
            -- end problematic join
            --
                 left join `accounting_records` as `u_monat`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `u_monat`.`id` and `u_monat`.`account_id` = 2 and
                              `u_monat`.`value` < 0 and month(`u_monat`.`date`) = '04' and year(`u_monat`.`date`) = 2021
                 left join `accounting_records` as `u_jahr`
                           on `accounting_records`.`id` = `u_jahr`.`id` and `u_jahr`.`account_id` = 2 and
                              `u_jahr`.`date` <= '2021-04-30'
        where `contracts`.`id` in (... many numbers ...)
        group by `cid`, `einrichtung`, `users`.`enr`, `users`.`surname`, `users`.`forename`
        order by `users`.`surname` asc
```

without `and ueberstunden.id >= 1`:

```
+--+-----------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-----+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table             |type  |possible_keys                                                  |key                                      |key_len|ref                            |rows |r_rows  |filtered|r_filtered|Extra                                          |
+--+-----------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-----+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|1 |SIMPLE     |facilities        |index |PRIMARY                                                        |facilities_name_unique                   |766    |NULL                           |5    |5.00    |100     |100       |Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort   |
|1 |SIMPLE     |contracts         |ref   |PRIMARY,contracts_facility_id_foreign,contracts_user_id_foreign|contracts_facility_id_foreign            |8      |azjournal.facilities.id        |17   |16.40   |79.61   |100       |Using index condition                          |
|1 |SIMPLE     |users             |eq_ref|PRIMARY                                                        |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.contracts.user_id    |1    |1.00    |100     |100       |                                               |
|1 |SIMPLE     |accounting_records|ref   |accounting_records_contract_id_foreign                         |accounting_records_contract_id_foreign   |8      |azjournal.contracts.id         |252  |680.45  |100     |100       |Using index                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |ist               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1    |1.00    |49.34   |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |nsf               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1    |1.00    |39.58   |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |ssf               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1    |1.00    |37.63   |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |fsf               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1    |1.00    |37.63   |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |nsp               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1    |1.00    |0.41    |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |ssp               |range |PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign|9      |NULL                           |251  |251.00  |100     |0         |Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |fsp               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1    |1.00    |0.41    |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |diff_soll_ist     |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1    |1.00    |50.57   |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |ueberstunden      |ALL   |PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |NULL                                     |NULL   |NULL                           |60689|60868.00|50.57   |0         |Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |u_monat           |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1    |1.00    |2.83    |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |u_jahr            |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1    |1.00    |2.83    |2.65      |Using where                                    |
+--+-----------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-----+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

with `and ueberstunden.id >= 1`:

```
+--+-----------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+----+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|id|select_type|table             |type  |possible_keys                                                  |key                                      |key_len|ref                            |rows|r_rows |filtered|r_filtered|Extra                                          |
+--+-----------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+----+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
|1 |SIMPLE     |facilities        |index |PRIMARY                                                        |facilities_name_unique                   |766    |NULL                           |5   |5.00   |100     |100       |Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort   |
|1 |SIMPLE     |contracts         |ref   |PRIMARY,contracts_facility_id_foreign,contracts_user_id_foreign|contracts_facility_id_foreign            |8      |azjournal.facilities.id        |17  |16.40  |79.61   |100       |Using index condition                          |
|1 |SIMPLE     |users             |eq_ref|PRIMARY                                                        |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.contracts.user_id    |1   |1.00   |100     |100       |                                               |
|1 |SIMPLE     |accounting_records|ref   |accounting_records_contract_id_foreign                         |accounting_records_contract_id_foreign   |8      |azjournal.contracts.id         |252 |680.45 |100     |100       |Using index                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |ist               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1   |1.00   |49.34   |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |nsf               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1   |1.00   |39.58   |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |ssf               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1   |1.00   |37.63   |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |fsf               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1   |1.00   |37.63   |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |nsp               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1   |1.00   |0.41    |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |ssp               |range |PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign|9      |NULL                           |251 |251.00 |100     |0         |Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |fsp               |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_salary_type_id_foreign              |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1   |1.00   |0.41    |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |diff_soll_ist     |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1   |1.00   |50.57   |0         |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |ueberstunden      |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1   |1.00   |50.57   |25.78     |Using where                                    |
|1 |SIMPLE     |u_monat           |range |PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |accounting_records_account_id_foreign    |9      |NULL                           |1718|1718.00|100     |0         |Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)|
|1 |SIMPLE     |u_jahr            |eq_ref|PRIMARY,accounting_records_account_id_foreign                  |PRIMARY                                  |8      |azjournal.accounting_records.id|1   |1.00   |2.83    |2.65      |Using where                                    |
+--+-----------+------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+----+-------+--------+----------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: As a first thing, you should replace those bits in the join condition: `month(fsp.date) = '04' and year(fsp.date) = 2021` because if you use functions, this will no longer be able to take advantage of any index and result in slow table scans. Use range checks instead, like this `fsp.date >= '2021-04-01' and fsp.date < '2021-05-01'`. After that, an index on `accounting_records` over `(id, salary_type_id, date)` could speed up those joins.

Comment: ...and the other index on `accounting_records` that would help in the joins goes over `(id, account_id, date)`.